# Redirect current page to another page on windows form web browser

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

How can I redirect the current page(A) to page(C) on web browser windows form c# once I’m done clicking the “I Accept” button. The response.redirect is not working on my code. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a web browser control within a C# Windows Form application, then you will need to use the 'Navigate' method attached to the webBrowser control.

```
this.webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.microsoft.com");
```

If your 'I Accept' button - is an Html element contained within the browser control, then you will need to use Javascript to trigger the page transition instead. As you will not have visibility of html element button clicks from the C# code.

Response.Redirect is only really needed if you are dealing with a server call.
In this case, you are a 'web client' and you just need to trigger a navigate.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
Server.Transfer("PageC.aspx");
```

Comment: This is on server side.